# Wifi stops working after suspend (18.04)

Tags: wireless, gnome, broadcom, ubuntu-gnome

The title says it all. My wireless stops working after computer suspends and the only fix I have is rebooting. My card is the BCM43142 and I'm using wl. Tried restarting network manager and tried reinstalling the driver. Both failed, any suggestions?

Comment: By "reinstalling the driver", do you mean some `apt` command, or do you mean `sudo rmmod $driver && sudo modprobe $driver`? The latter works for me (with appropriate `$driver` value) on a couple of models, and I've set it up so it does it automatically on resume.